Main window being obscured by other windows
When I click on certain areas of the current window, the window that was opened earlier and is located beneath opens up above the current one. How can this be fixed?
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

I was also having this issue. for me, this issue appeared after I changed from login with password to login automatically..
all I did is just reinstalling nvidia driver, and restart my PC.and it works..
but someone said you need to revert back login screen again to make it works.
here's some reference about this issue.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/3404#what-happened
24.04 Issue clicking window focuses on window behind/underneath
